# (MFC) Timer going wrongly

Tags: timer, mfc

i'm here to ask a question about WM_TIMER and SetTimer but when i type down this:

```
    void Timer::OnUpdateScreen()
    {
        TimerStillGoing=false;
        m_hour=HOUR;
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_HR, m_hour);
        m_minute=MINUTE;
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_MIN, m_minute);
        m_second=SECOND;
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_SEC, m_second);
        TimerStillGoing=true;
    }

    BOOL Timer::OnInitDialog() 
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

        SetTimer(1, 1000, NULL);

        return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                      // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
    }

    void Timer::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent) 
    {
        if(TimerStillGoing==false) goto GetOut;
        if(MINUTE==0)
        {
            HOUR=HOUR-1;
            MINUTE=60;
        }
        if(SECOND==0)
        {
            MINUTE=MINUTE-1;
            SECOND=60;
        }
        SECOND=SECOND-1;
        OnUpdateScreen();
    GetOut:
        CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
    }
```

code, i first get

(Here is supposed to be hour but gets ' '):(Here's sup. to be 30 but gets ' '):(Here's sup. to be 0 but gets ' ')

but a second later, i get
(nothing here):1:;

then later i get
(still nothng):1::

then,
(still nothing):1:9

then,
(still nothing):1:8

don't you think that's wierd? i'm not sure if my code is wrong or not. thx..

Comment: I don't understand what you expect for processing.  Your comments after "code, I first get"... is confusing at best.

Comment: Please also edit the question and show how m_hour, m_minute, m_second, HOUR, MINUTE and SECOND are declared

Answer (score 0):

SetDlgItemText needs a string (LPCTSTR). You seem to be passing it an integer instead. That should not compile.